# Is the German High-Speed Rail Station any different from normal train stations?

Tags: simcity-2013

[image: German High-Speed Rail Station in-game description]

Is the special German train station any different from the normal train station?  Do I get the same upgrades to it?  Do the German trains go faster?

Comment: I don't have Simcity, but i am pretty sure that a high speed train is faster then a normal train ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the EA store page:

> **More Transportation**
>
> Transport your Sims more efficiently with an exclusive Double Decker Bus station in
>   Britain and high-speed rail in Germany!

It seems like the German vs regular train-station for the same cost (upfront & maintenance) for better performance.